# Quarkus/Hibernate merge with OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true) gives HibernateException

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I am migrating from weblogic+eclipselink to quarkus+hibernate and get an error when trying to update a class through an endpoint.
Error is `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:`.
Imagine classes

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
class Parent {

    ...

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
@Builder
@Entity
class Child {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Parent parent;
}

@Transactional
@Applicationscoped
class ParentService {

public void updateParent(Parent updatedParent) {
        Optional<Parent> optionalExistingParent =
                parentRepository.getParentByID(updatedParent.getId());
        if (optionalExistingParent.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tried updating non-existing parent " + updatedParent.getGuid().toString());
        }
        // set back references for possible new children
        setBackReferences(updatedParent);
        parentRepository.merge(updatedParent);
    }

}
```

Situation: I retrieve a Parent object through a rest endpoint. Then I update a value from the parent (e.g. name) and send the updated parent object to a PUT endpoint. It then gets to the service layer, where I check if the parent is known, and if so, I call repository.merge().
It is at the repository.merge() call where the exception is thrown.

A lot of other stackoverflow questions regarding this error say that I need to clear() and addAll() the List, however (ignoring that I didn't even change anything in the list) all that code is hibernate code, there is no code written by me adding/removing to that list.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing `parent.getChildren.size()` and thus retrieving the data from the database before merging. It's silly, but `fetch=EAGER` does not work because there are multiple lists of children (including grandchildren) and then you get a HibernateException that you cannot fetch multiple bags.